# Digital Signature Certificate for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, digital-signature

How to find the digital signature certificate file for eclipse developer tool.

Comment: Sign or validate what to do what? There are more use cases for signing than the one you have in mind.

Comment: I just want to know where is the signed document of digital certificate is placed,

Comment: as the eclipse passes the security test and reported as the authenticated developer tool

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue what you're talking about. Please describe more precisely what you mean. Signature certificates are used differently for different things. Maybe a screenshot or a link would be helpful.

Comment: I am working in an organisation who has it own development tool and our development tool fails the security test as it has no digital signature certificate(said by security test) and i tried for eclipse & it passes the test so i just want to know where is the digital signature certification file for the eclipse , as it is open source and also provide authentication. just need help where is the file ?

Comment: On Windows a signature is contained in the executable `eclipse.exe` which is read by Windows to know if it is from a trusted vendor and to run it without further prompt or show a warning dialog instead (right-click `eclipse.exe` and show properties for details). Did you mean that? In Java also JARs can be signed. When upgrading Eclipse, these signatures are checked and similar to Windows a dialog will pop-up for unsigned plug-ins. And also Git commits can be signed using a GPG key as well as HTTPS domains have digital signature certificates...

Answer (score 0):

all the certs for eclipse plugins are placed in the manifest, find the jar you are interested in, unzip it by using jar xf  navigate to the expanded folder and look in META-INF, if jar is not on your classpath make sure you have a JDK installed not just the JRE